# How to retrieve images from Twitter API data

Tags: php, arrays, json, twitter

I'm setting up a page which will pull tweets based on a chosen topic - this is hard-coded for the moment and seems to work fine. The problem is, at the point where I am dealing with the JSON data (now converted to arrays), I'm struggling to target the "media_url" keys in the arrays which are needed to retrieve images.

Short of rewriting my code or reformatting it, I have tried multiple ways to target a post's media_url key to no avail. In other answers I've seen people succeed by utilizing the data as an object but I'm not sure how to go about that.

I've gotten this far by following the tutorial on https://iag.me/socialmedia/build-your-first-twitter-app-using-php-in-8-easy-steps/ - I'll note that people have asked about retrieving images on this page but have not been replied to, sad.

```
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
/** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
$settings = array(
'oauth_access_token' => "xxx",
'oauth_access_token_secret' => "xxx",
'consumer_key' => "xxx",
'consumer_secret' => "xxx"
);
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";
$getfield = '?q=%23life&count=20&tweet_mode=extended&include_entities=true';
$requestMethod = 'GET';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);

$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
if(array_key_exists("errors", $string)) {echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0]["message"]."</em></p>";exit();}
    foreach($string as $items)
    {
        if (is_array($items)){


            foreach($items as $item)
            {
                if ($item['user'] != null) {
                    echo $item['user']['name'] . "&nbsp" . "|" . "&nbsp" . "@" . $item['user']['screen_name']."<br />";
                    echo $item['full_text'] . "<br />";
                    echo $item['created_at']."<br />";
                    echo $item['entities']>['media'][0]['media_url'] . "<br />";
                    echo '<hr>';
                    var_dump($item);
                } 
                else {
                    return;
                }
            }

        }
    }



?>
```

I've run into many errors while trying to reformat the line `echo $item['entities']>['media'][0]['media_url'] . "<br />";` and have gotten to the point of reaching out on here. Hoping I won't have to reformat it as an object but It's looking like I may.

Comment: What's up with the `>` in `$item['entities']>['media']`? Try removing that.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson OMG that works lol thank you 

EDIT: actually that does work but i'm still getting the error "Undefined index: media"

Comment: If you have `>`, it will evaluate if `$item['entities']` is greater than `['media'][0]['media_url']"`. If you want to fetch the value, it should just be: `$item['entities']['media'][0]['media_url']` if that is the correct structure of the array.

Comment: How strange is it that it works yet still returns an error? Removing ['media'] also stops it working

Comment: Well, the code `echo $item['entities']>['media'][0]['media_url'] . "<br />"` would probably just throw an undefined index and echo the value `1`. That line of code would not give you the value of `$item['entities']['media'][0]['media_url']`. [Here's an example](https://3v4l.org/bLKim)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I think I can get it working from here, seems like it was just a syntax issue. I hadn't seen anyone doing this with the API without using the data as an object so I got a bit confused trying to find an "inbetween" syntax. If you add your suggestion as an answer I'll give you the win :)

Answer (score 2):

As per @MagnusEriksson's comment, my issue was caused by the incorrect syntax I was using.

`$item['entities']['media'][0]['media_url']` has allowed me to target the index I was looking for and I can now display the image for a tweet :) Thanks Magnus!